# Is there a way to check whether the user input text box is active, in WebChat?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am using Bot Framework WebChat as the UI for my Bot. For my scenario, I would need to know if the user is currently entering some data into the Input text box, either by voice or by typing. Is there any way in WebChat to check if there is currently some input being fed to the input box? I am not using React in my app, and hence might not be able to use the various React Hooks provided by WebChat when hosted with React.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use an `eventListener()` placed in your page. Presently, the input box is located in a div below the transcript window and has a role of "form". Inside that is a div with a class of "main". In there you can locate the input element of which there should only be one.

Now, there may be other elements in Web Chat with the role of "form", either natively or added as a function of some other Web Chat (or other) code. So, you will need to write your code with this in mind. Below, I also select all elements with class "main" inside "form" for the same reason even though there is only one. If you're confident, you can cut this step out.

Out of the box, this will work:

```js
const form = document.querySelectorAll('form');
const main = form[0].querySelectorAll('main');
const input = main[0].querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  console.log('typing');
})
```

Obviously, you can experiment with other [event types](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) to find the right fit for your need.

Hope of help!

Comment: This would help in the case of input in the form of typing, but my use case is mostly voice driven, is there another method for that as well?